# Older Post and Newer Post Wordpress codex not working on my blog page

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I have a Website where i sued the wordpress codex to put older post and newer post but it wont effect. im not so pro at debuging code. could anyone help me please. i also have read many articles and post about this but i did no have an answer, hope that someone can help me. thanks a lot

```
<div id="main" class="blog-list-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <header class="page-header">
                        <!--<h1 class="page-title"><?php //the_title(); ?></h1>-->
                    </header>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </article>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="section blog-posts-list">
            <?php
                $args = [
        'posts_per_page'   => 10,
                    'offset'  => 0,
                    'orderby' => 'post_date',
                    'order'   => 'DESC',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                ];
                $posts= get_posts( $args );

                foreach ( $posts as $post ) :
                    setup_postdata($post);
            ?>

            <article class="clearfix">
                <div class="post-category">
                    <?php
                        $categories = get_the_category();
                        echo $categories[0]->name;
                    ?>
                </div>
                <a href="<?= the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </a>
                <div class="meta">
                    <span class="author"></span>
                    <span class="timestamp"></span>
                </div>
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                    <a href="<?= the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-thumbnail">
                        <?= the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="<?= the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more-link">Read more...</a>
                </div>
            </article>

            <?php
                endforeach;
            ?>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first of all do one thing in your config.php define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: and then tell me what is the error or if there is no error then what result  r u gating after this code ..

Comment: there is no error but how can i put pagination or old post button on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `get_posts` for paginated queries as it is not meant for that. `get_posts` legally breaks pagination to speed up non paginated queries by passing `no_found_rows=true` to `WP_Query`. Also, `get_posts` only returns the `$posts` property from the `WP_Query` object, so this all together makes pagination of `get_posts` a total nightmare.

For paginated queries you should be using `WP_Query` instead.

### ADDITIONAL RESOURCES

- [`next_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query)
- [`previous_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link)